# Literature for the longest Element of the Weylgroup for $GL(n,K)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, weyl-group, general-linear-group

I am looking for literature where I can find how the longest Element of the Weyl group looks like for $G=GL(n,K)$ over the diagonal matrices in $G$. I don't even need a proof. But I have no idea where to find it.
Would be great, if somebody can help me :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

You can find an explicit formula in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54926/longest-element-of-weyl-groups (in the question itself).
The answers give some more general results on other types.

Comment: Can you tell me the notation for the $s_i$ in the beginning of your link?

Comment: @JaZonk Those are the simple reflections (in the language of Weyl groups associated to Lie groups or algebraic groups, they are the reflections corresponding to the simple roots).